# how to add some symbol before page number?

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]

I want to add some coloured symbols before page number in my content as shown above, how does it work?

By the help of Steven B. Segletes, my problem solved, here is my tex :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,openany,11pt]{ctexbook}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xpatch,xcolor,tocloft}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{660pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{45pt}

% SET STAR DEFINITIONS
\def\blackstar{\textcolor{black}{\Pifont{pzd}{\ding{110}}}}
\def\redstar{\textcolor{red}{\Pifont{pzd}{\ding{110}}}}
\def\orangestar{\textcolor{orange}{\Pifont{pzd}{\ding{110}}}}
\def\yellowstar{\textcolor{yellow}{\Pifont{pzd}{\ding{110}}}}
% MAGIC TO EXTRACT SUBSECTION NUMBER AND SET IT IN \tmp

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\CTEXsetup[name={,},number={}]{chapter}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\addvspace{2pt}\Large\bf\color{black}\filright}{\contentspush{\thecontentslabel}}{}{}
\titlecontents{section}[3em]{}{\contentslabel{2em}}{}{\titlerule*[0.5pc]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\l@subsection}{\ifnum}{\extract#1\relax\ifnum}{}{}
\def\extract#1#2#3\relax{\xdef\tmp{#2}}
\makeatother

% CONFIGURE tocloft PARAMETERS TO USE \csname stars\tmp\endcsname AS PAGE FONT
\cftsetpnumwidth{3em}


\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\csname symbol\tmp\endcsname\,}
% MACRO \setstars TO DEFINE STARS IN GIVEN SUBSECTION TITLE
\newcommand\setsecstars[2]{\expandafter\gdef\csname symbol#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\setstars[1]{\protect\setsecstars{\thesubsection}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hspace*{\fill}Contents\hspace*{\fill}}

\begin{center}
\tableofcontents
\end{center}
\clearpage

\chapter{Chapter}
\clearpage

\section{Section}
\clearpage
\subsection{subsectionA\setstars{\orangestar\orangestar\blackstar}}
\clearpage
\subsection{subsectionB\setstars{\yellowstar\yellowstar\blackstar}}
\clearpage
\subsection{subsectionC\setstars{\redstar\blackstar\blackstar}}
\end{document}
```

But there is a problem of the contents that the dotted line in section stops before reaching the page number. 
[image]
So can I somehow get the dots until the section page number starts?

Comment: since the creation of you table of contents is a build-in macro, it won't be super easy to modify it (at least for me). A quick'n'dirty workaround could be to use this trick in your document: `\subsection[Title in the ToC \macroThatDefinesTheStars{2}{yellow}]{Title in the text}`. But stars will then appear *before* the dotted line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Just to be clear, you do not want this symbol on the actual page numbers themselves, only in the contents, is that right?

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like this. Be careful to reset the command `\insertstars` to relax as `\addcontentsline` is also used be figure etc. It is up-to-you to replace the * with the symbols you want.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}          % deutschsprachig, silbentrennung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}          % Eingabe von Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}          % Schriftkodierung, Silbentrennung für Wörter mit Umlauten
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\usepackage{hyperref}

%after hyperref
\patchcmd\addcontentsline{\thepage}{\insertstars\thepage}{}{}

\NewDocumentCommand\threestars{ } {\textcolor{yellow}{***}*\,}
\NewDocumentCommand\twostars  { } {\textcolor{yellow}{**}**\,}
\NewDocumentCommand\redstars  { } {\textcolor{red}{****}\,}

\newcommand\insertstars{}
\newcommand\setstarcommand[1]{\renewcommand\insertstars{#1}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{8ex}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\section{A}

\setstarcommand\threestars
\subsection{abc}
\setstarcommand\relax

\begin{figure}
\caption{abc}
\end{figure}

\setstarcommand\twostars
\subsection{abc}
\setstarcommand\relax

\setstarcommand\redstars
\subsection{abc}
\setstarcommand\relax

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here I use a `tocloft` solution.  I patch `\l@subsection` to save the subsection number in `\tmp`.  Then, I use `\csname stars\tmp\endcsname` as the font to set the subsection page number.  But since `\tmp` is unique to each subsection, so is the "font" macro.

These font macros are defined in each `\subsection` argument, following the title itself, using the `\setstars` macro.  The stars only show up in the toc page number, not the subsection title itself.

So the trick is to use the `tocloft` page font macro, `\cftsubsecpagefont`, unique to each subsection, to set the stars.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch,xcolor,tocloft}
% SET STAR DEFINITIONS
\def\blackstar{\textcolor{black}{$\star$}}
\def\redstar{\textcolor{red}{$\star$}}
\def\orangestar{\textcolor{orange}{$\star$}}
\def\yellowstar{\textcolor{yellow!80!red}{$\star$}}
% MAGIC TO EXTRACT SUBSECTION NUMBER AND SET IT IN \tmp
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\l@subsection}{\ifnum}{\extract#1\relax\ifnum}{}{}
\def\extract#1#2#3\relax{\xdef\tmp{#2}}
\makeatother
% CONFIGURE tocloft PARAMETERS TO USE \csname stars\tmp\endcsname AS PAGE FONT 
\cftsetpnumwidth{2em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\csname stars\tmp\endcsname\,}
% MACRO \setstars TO DEFINE STARS IN GIVEN SUBSECTION TITLE
\newcommand\setsecstars[2]{\expandafter\gdef\csname stars#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\setstars[1]{\protect\setsecstars{\thesubsection}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{section}
\clearpage
\subsection{subsection A\setstars{\orangestar\orangestar\blackstar}}
\clearpage~\clearpage~\clearpage
\subsection{subsection B\setstars{\yellowstar\yellowstar\blackstar}}
\clearpage~\clearpage~\clearpage
\subsection{subsection C\setstars{\redstar\blackstar\blackstar}}
\end{document}
```

[image]